# How do I with Espresso check if a DialogFragment is visible and only then perform an action?

Tags: android, android-espresso

What I wish to do is to check if a specific `DialogFragment` is visible and only if its visible I want to execute a code like this `onView(withId(R.id.start_app)).perform(click());`

Right now I have this code which I cant use in a if-condition.
Both codes in this method will run regardless of if the `Dialogfragment` is visible or not.`

```
@Test
public void testHowDoIBecomeCustomerButtonX() {
    onView(withId(R.id.cancel_button))
            .inRoot(isDialog())
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    onView(withId(R.id.becoming_customer)).perform(click());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is wrap your condition into a `try-catch` where the condition throws an exception if not satisfied and therefore leaving the `try` block.

It could look something like this:

```
    try {
        onView(withId(R.id.cancel_button)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.becoming_customer)).perform(click());
    } catch (NoMatchingViewException e) {
    }
```

If the first check for the `cancel_button` fails the second line is not executed. You just have to make sure your first condition is evaluating correctly.

But generally speaking this is a [**bad pattern**](http://xunitpatterns.com/Conditional%20Test%20Logic.html). There is a reason why this is not possible without using some kind of hack. You should avoid conditions in your tests at all! It would be much better to have two separate test cases where in one test case the dialog appears and you go on with your tests and in a second one it does not appear and you go on from there.